# User is always null when trying to get user Name .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to get the Name of actually logged user with this function:

```
public string GetUserName()
{
    return User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
}
```

This is how I call this function from .cshtml file:

```
@{
    RoleController role = new RoleController();
}
    @if (role.GetUserName()==("test"))
    {
        <li class="@ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext)"><a asp-page="./NewVisit">Umów wizytę</a></li>
    }
```

But when method `GetUserName()` is called, I get a `NullReferenceException` on `User`. I try to log out and log in again when app running but it doesn't work.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That is not how to access `User` in the View. The controller needs to be created by the framework, which would populate it based on he request.

I suggest creating an extension method to provide the desired functionality

```
public static string GetUserName(this IPrincipal user)
{
    return ((ClaimsPrincipal) user)?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value ?? string.Empty;
}
```

You have access to the `User` in the view so you can call the extension method

```
@if (User.GetUserName()==("test"))
{
    <li class="@ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext)"><a asp-page="./NewVisit">Umów wizytę</a></li>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating new RoleController() is the same as accessing the controller.
In your situation the easiest would be to use `ViewBag` to save and use your result later.

so in controller you do:

```
ViewBag.IsTestUser = GetUserName()=="test";
```

in your cshtml, use it as:

```
@if (ViewBag.IsTestUser)
    {
        <li class="@ManageNavPages.PersonalDataNavClass(ViewContext)"><a asp-page="./NewVisit">Umów wizytę</a></li>
    }
```

Comment: I try your solution but I have also  NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
CardiologicClinic_WebApp.Controllers.RoleController.GetUserName() in RoleController.cs, line 64